# Troubleshooting a potential water leak

Tags: water, leak

My water company recently sent me a letter saying they suspect I have a water leak somewhere, since the digital meter has had a reading every hour for 24 consecutive hours. I checked everywhere I could think of (sinks, showers, outdoor faucets, even crawlspace, etc..) and everything is perfectly dry. The outdoor faucets are also covered with [insulated covers](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hard-Outdoor-Faucet-Cover-1981/204759083).

I obviously don't want to ignore a leak since it could result in expensive damage over time, but I'm not sure where else to look. How can I troubleshoot this?

To clarify, the letter was sent last month but I just opened my mail now. It's theoretically possible the leak is no longer happening but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Toilet tank leaking into the toilet bowl is one hidden leak spot.  Outdoor faucets if they got frozen, thaw enough to leak and froze again.  Insulation only helps so much.

Comment: Does your meter actually have a readout on it, or is it completely electronic with no display?  If it has a display, confirm the water company's information is correct by reading the meter, making sure you have no water running for an hour, and then reading it again and seeing if there is any change.  Did the letter say how long they've measured this, or only for a day that this happened?  If nothing else, call them (or go online if you can get your meter info directly) and see if it's a continuing trend or not.  Usually a leak doesn't stop by itself.

Comment: Nearly all water meters have a sensitive flow indicator that will visibly advance in 1 minute if there is a leak. Do  you have a key to open the meter cover?

Comment: If you have landscaping irrigation, try turning off the master valve for a period while also not using any house water.